# USB device exceeds power limits

Tags: settings, usb, windows

OK, the `android studio` really drive me crazy.

At first, AVD cannot launch and I have post my issue here to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33417842/avd-not-running and failed to create new virtual device https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33419733/throwable-failed-to-create-the-sd-card

After install Android SDK Tool from sdk manager and HAXM installer, it finally can lunch but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33527421/emulator-cannot-start-up.

After I increase the emulator memory, my emulator works fine but I cannot use real device to run my project.

> Error: Power Surge On Hub Port: A USB device has exceeded the power
>   limits of its hub port

I'm not sure whether the error exists is due to the emulator setting because it can run before  the emulator memory get increased. Anyone can help? It totally frustrating.

Comment: The error message seems to be [a general error message on Windows](http://support.wdc.com/KnowledgeBase/answer.aspx?ID=1488), thus this doesn't seem to be Android related issue (more like your PC issue). Consider asking this on [su] instead.

Comment: Before that, it seems [there is already a case like this on Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/244187/windows-xp-power-surge-on-hub-port). Please read it first, and if it doesn't help, then consider asking a new question with detailed info.